# Google Analytics - treat https and http as a single "property"

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a site on which users are supposed to jump back and forth between protocols (http vs https). For example, they may land on https://example.com/index.html, and then click through to http://example.com/test.html.

In order to accurately gauge the user behavior flow on google analytics, I need to treat both of these protocols as one single property in my GA setup.

google, however, makes you select a single protocol when defining a new web property. What is the best way to handle this? Let's assume https is my default - how can I trigger a pageview from the http site and have it be counted towards the https site's analytics?

I know there is a forceSSL option, but there is not much documentation around that:

> By default, Google Analytics will match the protocol of the host page
>   when sending outbound requests. To force Google Analytics to always
>   send data using SSL, even from insecure pages (HTTP), set the forceSSL
>   field to true

Will this accomplish what I'm looking to do? Sending the data via SSL does not necessarily correlate to them recording the data as an SSL event.

Comment: You'll collect data regardless of the protocol in the same property. the `forceSSL` option only makes *all* requests use https instead of just those on https pages.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this issue is the following:

As far as Google is concerned, your HTTP and HTTPS properties ARE two separate entities.

The only way to lump them together is to force the entire site to use SSL, thus removing the HTTP property.

If this is an option, it will have the added benefit of increasing your search ranking.